# SIgnalR - An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, nunit, autofac

i am having an issue regarding a signalr (version 1.2.2. I cannot update toto 2+)/autofac/Nunit implementation. I am using an MVC client with a WCF service whixh pushes notifications to client. When I' m running the app using the web client and the service everything works as expected. When i try to test my service through NUnit everytime i try to create the hubcontext

```
GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProductHub>()
```

i get

```
An item with the same key has already been added.
```

here is the full stack trace

```
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.ReflectedHubDescriptorProvider.BuildHubsCache()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.ReflectedHubDescriptorProvider.TryGetHub(String hubName, HubDescriptor& descriptor)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.DefaultHubManager.c__DisplayClass1.b__0(IHubDescriptorProvider p)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.DefaultHubManager.GetHub(String hubName)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubManagerExtensions.EnsureHub(IHubManager hubManager, String hubName, IPerformanceCounter[] counters)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext(String hubName)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext[T]()
```

Here is the autofac and signalr registration in global.asax service file

```
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration { EnableCrossDomain = true });
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<Product_WCF_Service>().AsSelf();
        builder.RegisterType<DbFactory>().As<IDbFactory>();
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(
            new[] {
                typeof(ProductService).Assembly
            })
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(
            new[] {
                typeof(ProductRepository).Assembly
            })
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();

        builder.RegisterType<ProductHub>().ExternallyOwned();    
        var container = builder.Build();
        container.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();
        container.Resolve<IDbFactory>();
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(container);
        AutofacHostFactory.Container = container;
        AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
    }
```

My service implementation

```
public class Product_WCF_Service : IProduct_WCF_Service
{
    IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork;
    IProductService ProductService;

    public Product_WCF_Service(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IProductService productService)
    {
        this.ProductService = productService;
        this.UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
```

}

And my NUnit test which causes the exception to be thrown

```
[TestFixture]
public class WCF_Product_Service_Tests
{
    private Mock<IProduct_WCF_Service> ProductWCFService;
    private Mock<IUnitOfWork> UnitOfWork;
    private Mock<IProductService> ProductService;
    public WCF_Product_Service_Tests()
    {
        this.ProductWCFService = new Mock<IProduct_WCF_Service>();
        this.UnitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        this.ProductService = new Mock<IProductService>();
    }

    [Test]
    public void RetreiveDataFromWCF_Service()
    {
        byte commitStatus = 1;
        string response = string.Empty;
        var service = new Product_WCF_Service(this.UnitOfWork.Object, this.ProductService.Object);
        service.CreateProduct("", out response, out commitStatus);
    }}
```

It's driving me crazy as i cannot test my service at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I searched around and finally i found a solution. I' leave it here just in case someone finds this useful

when registering autofac i enabled the property injection

```
                        var signalRConfig = new HubConfiguration();
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<ServiceHub>().ExternallyOwned(); // SignalR hub registration
        builder.Register(i => signalRConfig.Resolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>().GetHubContext<ServiceHub>()).ExternallyOwned();
        builder.RegisterType<Product_WCF_Service>().AsSelf();
        builder.RegisterType<DbFactory>().As<IDbFactory>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(
            new[] {
                typeof(ProductService).Assembly
            })
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(
            new[] {
                typeof(ProductRepository).Assembly
            })
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();

        builder.RegisterType<Product_WCF_Service>()
            .PropertiesAutowired();
        var container = builder.Build();
        signalRConfig.Resolver = new Autofac.Integration.SignalR.AutofacDependencyResolver(container);
        signalRConfig.EnableCrossDomain = true;
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(signalRConfig);
        AutofacHostFactory.Container = container;
        AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
```

In my service i added the hubcontext as a property in

```
public class Product_WCF_Service : IProduct_WCF_Service{

    IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork;
    IProductService ProductService;
    public IHubContext InstanceHubContext { get; set; }

    public Product_WCF_Service(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IProductService productService)
    {
        this.ProductService = productService;
        this.UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
```

and it worked as expected! I can now access the hubcontext as usual

```
this.InstanceHubContext.Clients.All.onNotSavedProduct(message);
```

Of course you will also need the Autofac.Integration.SignalR and Autofac.Integration.Wcf packages